# Proving B Congruent C given AB congruent AC

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, congruences

This is a very trivial question, i seem to have arrived at a proof for an excercise but the proof just doesn't feel.. right. It is too small and simple.

The fact to be proved is that if $AB\equiv AC$ and $A \not\equiv 0$, then $B\equiv  C$.

My proof simply uses the identities that $A\equiv A$ always, and if $A \equiv A'$ and $B \equiv B'$, then $AB \equiv A'B'$

Using this fact, i show that $1/a\equiv1/a$ and as already stated, $AB\equiv AC$.

Hence, $(AB)*1/a\equiv(AC) * 1/a$ or $B\equiv C$.
Is this correct?

[P.S: I'm sorry, i didn't know how to get the triple equal to sign in here to signify congruence. Editor's note: This now obsolete, JL]

Comment: Direct consequence of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma). $p\mid a(b-c),\, \gcd(p,a)=1\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid b-c$.

Comment: Search for StackExchange LaTeX guide.

Comment: Of course, it only generally holds for prime moduli.

Comment: Congruent modulo what? A subgroup? Where do A,B,C live?

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply false modulo $6$.